# Getting Assembly Version of a class that implements interface through interface method

Tags: c#, version, .net-assembly

My classes all implement an interface. This interface stores some funtions for general functionality.

One of those funtionalities is Logging. In this Logging function I want to get the AssemblyVersion of the Class that implements the interface.

My problem is that `Assembly.GetExectuingAssembly()` will return the AssemblyVersion of the Interface.

How can I get the Assembly Version of the implementing class?

Comment: How about ``this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version`` ?

Comment: I guess the complicated part is, that the implementing classes aren't in the same namespace as the interface... They're completely seperate projects

Comment: I asked already once on the now deleted answer, but why should that be a problem? Can you clarify yourself?

Comment: Well, I just debugged your code and it seems to work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version
```

Comment: Well, surely not *this*.  Probably varname.GetType() where varname stores the interface reference.

Comment: @HansPassant As I understood OP, he has an Interface like ``public interface IFoo { string Version { get; } }`` and he wanted to know how the implementation will look like in the derived classes so it should look like ``public Foo : IFoo { public string Version { get { return this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(); } } }`` - so yes, if I understood correctly it would be ``this``, but chances are high I misinterpreted. :)